# OCaml match shorthand

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, ocaml

When I first looked at the use of the `function` keyword in OCaml, I gained the impression that it was syntax sugar to eliminate the `match x with` line for a pattern match.

However, I see that there is a signature difference between the two as in the example below. In what circumstances would you wish to use the `function` example?

```
type e = Foo | Bar

let eval1 exp =
match exp with
| Foo -> "Foo"
| Bar -> "Bar"

let eval2 exp = function
| Foo -> "Foo"
| Bar -> "Bar"
```

The first function has a signature of `val eval1 : e -> bytes = <fun>`

The second function has a signature of `val eval2 : 'a -> e -> bytes = <fun>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `eval2`, using `function`, the argument that is matched on is implicit. `exp` is unused here, and should give you a compiler warning (unless you've turned it off). If you remove the `exp` argument the signatures should be identical.

Or in other words, `function ...` is not syntax sugar for just `match exp with ...`, but for `fun exp -> match exp with ...`